# How to make React component wait for http call to return

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am learning react-redux-saga and I am making an HTTP call with saga.  I connect the result using mapStateToProps however, my react component errors out before the http call returns.  I get something along the lines of "Cannot find name of undefined" on the first line of my return statement.

How do I get my component to wait?  this.props.user will be undefined for a split second while the http call is being made but the call never returns because my application just dies due to the runtime error.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
class ImageGenerator extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        let user = this.props.image;
        console.log("USer", this.props.image);
        return (
            <div>
                Name: {user.name.first} {user.name.last}
                Phone: {user.phone}
                Date of Birth: {user.dob.date} <br/>
                Age: {user.dob.age} <br/>
                Email: {user.dob} <br />
                Gender: {user.gender} <br/>
                City: {user.location.city } <br />
                State: {user.location.State } <br />
                Street: {user.location.street } <br />
                <img src={user.picture.medium} alt="No Image Found"/>
                {/* <button onClick={getNewImage}>New Image</button> */}
                <button>Add to Favorites</button> 
           </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log("State", state);
    return { image: state.image };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getNewImage: () =>
            dispatch({
                type: NEXT_IMAGE
            })
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ImageGenerator);
```

Comment: I assume because it's asynchronous, `user` is undefined before the call finishes. Give a default value or show some kind of loading UI.

Comment: Never have your component wait for something asynchronous to return before rendering. As @Li357 said, give the properties default values and preferably have some visual indicator that the component is waiting for a response from somewhere, so the users known what's happening.

Comment: If you don't want your component to render before the data is available you need to make the parent fetch the required data and only render the child when it is available.

Comment: I tried passing the prop value via the parent but its the same problem but in the parent.  I would essentially be passing a undefined value to the child and the child would fail.  Looking at the answer the tenerary operator is probably what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases you can use && operator/ ternary operator to check whether the object has data or the object is undefined. These days most of the React questions are having these issues but the solution is very simple.

Check below updated code for better understanding.

```
  class ImageGenerator extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
       render() {
            const { user }= this.props;
            console.log("USer", this.props.image);
            return (
                 <div>
                      {user && user != undefined && (Name: {user.name.first} {user.name.last}
                     Phone: {user.phone}
                    Date of Birth: {user.dob.date} <br/>
                    Age: {user.dob.age} <br/>
                   Email: {user.dob} <br />
                   Gender: {user.gender} <br/>
                   City: {user.location.city } <br />
                   State: {user.location.State } <br />
                  Street: {user.location.street } <br />
                 <img src={user.picture.medium} alt="No Image Found"/>)}
                  {/* <button onClick={getNewImage}>New Image</button> */}
                 <button>Add to Favorites</button> 
              </div>
             )
        }
    }

     const mapStateToProps = state => {
          console.log("State", state);
            return { user: state.image };
     };

   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
         return {
             getNewImage: () =>
                dispatch({
                     type: NEXT_IMAGE
                })
             }
         };

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ImageGenerator);
```

Comment: NP. Keep Learning